# Derivative and equation with floor function

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics

Let **d** and **x** be integers and

$f(x) = x + \lceil\frac{d}{x + 1}\rceil$

I need the minimum of $f(x)$, the idea is to find the derivative of $f(x)$.

However, how can I solve
$\frac{d}{dx} (\lceil u \rceil)$ ?

Comment: You are asking the wrong question.  That function is not differentiable.  The question should be "how to minimize it?"

Comment: OTOH, if you really want to differentiate _something_, try differentiating $g(x) = x + {d \over x+1}$.  This may give you useful insight for how to minimize $f$.

Comment: Are you sure about the problem statement ? Where does it come from ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot solve $\frac{d}{dx} (\lceil u \rceil)$ because it is not an equation.

Perhaps you want to know what is is.
As u is not defined, it is impossible to determine the derivative.
Is u intended to be function of x?  If it is, then say so.

Exercise.  Show that $\frac{d}{dx} (\lceil x \rceil)$ = 0
when x is not an integer and does not exist otherwise,

If perchance u is a function of x, then use the result of the
exercise and the chain rule to determine $\frac{d}{dx} (\lceil u \rceil)$.

Comment: $\frac d{dx}\lceil u\rceil=\delta_{\{u\}}\frac{du}{dx}$, i.e.  it is defined and zero where $u$ is non-integer.

Comment: Delta is a thing?

Comment: Dirac delta. It only makes sense in the frame of *distributions*.

Comment: So it is nonsense, @YvesDaoust

Comment: The theory of distributions is certainly not nonsense.

Comment: @YvesDaoust.  It is in the current context.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the derivative is not a good idea because

- the function is discontinuous in the real domain,
- the unknown is restricted to be integer.

In addition, the function is unbounded below (for $x<-d-2$, it reduces to $x$) and cannot have a minimum.